# Getting an error when assigning single value from table to declared variable in ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am writing procedure for Oracle DB 10g/11g and i need to assign spesific date value to the variable. Code is below.

```
DECLARE 
    date_from DATE := NULL;
DECLARE 
    d_count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO d_count FROM TABLE_X;

    IF d_count = 0 THEN
        SELECT MIN(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_Y;
    ELSE
        SELECT MAX(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_X;
    END IF;
END;
```

When I run this, I am getting this error.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE 
    date_from DATE := NULL;
DECLARE 
    d_count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO d_count FROM TABLE_X;

    IF d_count = 0 THEN
        SELECT MIN(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_Y;
    ELSE
        SELECT MAX(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_X;
    END IF;
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

    begin function pragma procedure subtype type <and identifier>
    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
    exist prior
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 13, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
    
    ( begin case declare and exception exit for goto if loop mod
    null pragma raise return select update while with
    <an identifier><a double-quoted
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usuallz a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I have T-SQL experience, however very new to PL/SQL in OracleDB.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what can you see at `line 3, column 1`? Correct, another `declare` keyword that should not be there. Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D) about the syntax, it doesn't require any questions.

Comment: Thank you, I should be more careful and thanks for sharing documentation. I just started using Oracle DB with task, normally I like to read documentation before I start something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used extra declare.  This should be ok:

```
DECLARE 
    date_from DATE := NULL; 
    d_count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO d_count FROM TABLE_X;

    IF d_count = 0 THEN
        SELECT MIN(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_Y;
    ELSE
        SELECT MAX(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_X;
    END IF;
END;
```

Basic template for scripts:

```
declare 
  -- Local variables here
  i integer;
begin
  --  statements here
end;
```

Basic Template for procedures:

```
procedure TEST(Name in out type, Name in out type, ...) is
begin
  
end TEST;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even though my question was bit silly, your answer and templates are good for me to understand the structure of scripts and procedures.

Comment: yes, its very smiliar to TSQL . If you have a chance to use PL/SQL Developer IDE, it has really nice ready template section that you can use , it may boost your speed too.  just an advice. i wish you the best on your new area :)

Comment: @nedensel anyway it will be good to check the documentation. Every SQL statement in it has a bunch of examples that demonstrate basic syntax, different usage of syntax elements, performance differences. For example, [PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-8514540B-FE23-41E1-9F72-AB8D726DEE8F)

Comment: @Ali Fidanli I will check it out, thank you again. I also bit rushed myself without checking everything properly :)

Comment: @astentx I was just using T-SQL habbits without reading documentation first. However, I will definitely read to prevent this kind of syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, only one `DECLARE` is enough.

Besides (although not an error),

- variable that is declared is `NULL` by default; you don't have to specify it (that's `DATE_FROM`)
- `d_count` is used to accept result of the `count` function; if nothing is found in `table_x`, count will be `0` anyway so you don't have to specify `d_count`'s initial value either

So:

```
DECLARE
   date_from  DATE;
   d_count    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO d_count FROM TABLE_X;

   IF d_count = 0 THEN
      SELECT MIN(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_Y;
   ELSE
      SELECT MAX(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_X;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Side note: `SELECT MAX(TRX_DATE) INTO date_from FROM TABLE_X;` may be avoided if you add `max(trx_date)` to the first statement.